# Installing centos, error - failed to find suitable stage1 device

Tags: linux, centos, system-installation

On my machine i already have windows. On free space of 100gb, I created 3 partitions for new centos installation - /boot 500mb, swap 8gb, and / of remaining 90gb. All are of type standard partition, and file system type ext4(except swap which is of type swap)

Its giving me error checking storage configuration - failed to find suitable stage1 device:Efi system partition must be mounted on one of /boot/efi

Whats the reason for this? Also will it interfere in dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

First a caveat - I don't really know how this works.

But from what I've read, you need a separate partition (of type vfat) that's mounted in /boot/efi. It should be about 200Mb.